# Preserving data binding when changing instance

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Is it possible to preserve a data binding of a variable when a new instance of that variable is created?

What I have is a design that stores all user inputs in a winform application so these values can be stored/loaded via `xml`. What I am finding is when I reload the design into my program the data bindings are lost as new instances of the variables are created. I am managing to get by so far by using reflection to copy the new values of data on to the currently data bound instances but this only works up to one level of depth.

Example xml file:

```
<design>
   <level1>
      <myRadioButton>true</myRadioButton>//This value is copied onto the 
                                         //data bound object
   </level1>
<level1>
   <level2>
       <myRadioButton>true</myRadioButton>//This value is not as a new instance
                   // of level2 is made removing the data binding instance object
   </level2>
<level1>
</design>
```

Example data bindings:

```
radioButton.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Instances.Variables.Design.Level1,
                "myRadioButton", false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
radioButton.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Instances.Variables.Design.Level1.Level2, 
               "myRadioButton", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

If any other code example is needed then please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the databinding of all controls on your form. If the current datasource is your old xml-objects, remove the databinding, and add a new databinding with the same parameters except that it should use your new xml-objects.

Basically 'refresh' all necessary databindings by removing the current one, and adding a new one.

Comment: Ah so basically you are saying just call all of my data binding methods after I've reloaded the design in? (I presume my databindings have already been removed when the instance is removed)

Comment: @Sayse Not sure what 'instance' you mean, but normally, no, the databindings are not removed automatically. If with 'instance' you mean your datasource, then no, your instance might be removed from where-ever you store it, but it is still in memory, and referenced by the databindings.
You will have to remove the databindings manually.

Comment: Ok right I understand, and yes that was the instance I was referring to. I will try out your suggestion within the next hour and accept your answer. Thanks!